How to properly ask contributors to waive their copyright interests to dedicate them to Public domain?
Right now I'm setting up a project, a game engine, and decided that it is the project's best interest to be dedicated to the public domain instead of being GPLv3+; thus I'm using the UNLICENSE license (if that makes sense). So I have the file in place and adding this header to all the files that it makes sense to have it (CMakeLists.txt, *.cpp, *.hpp, shell scripts, etc.):

This file is part of <Project>

<Project> is Free Software (free as in freedom!), all copyright interest
in this software are dedicated to the public domain. See UNLICENSE for
more.

Since I'm starting this project from scratch and expect an eventual surge of volunteers making contributions, I've put in place rules for doing so, and one of the most important rules is providing a waiver of their copyright interests, these are the instructions I have so far:
# Waiver of Your Copyright Interests

> [!WARNING]
> If you are contributing in capacity of an employee of some formal
> organization you need to additionally ask for a copyright disclaimer
> signed by a company officer

To contribute to this project, you must explicitly release any
substantial contributions to the public domain to ensure <Project>
remains free of any copyright claims.

## Step-by-Step Process

1. Copy the `WAIVER` file to the `waivers` folder. Name it using your
legal name or the name configured in your Git settings, along with
your email.

    ```sh
    cp WAIVER waivers/"John Smith <john@example.com>"
    ```

> [!TIP]
> If you already have a commit authored by you in a branch you can use
> `git` to return the correct name in the expected format with `git
> log -1 --pretty=format:'%an <%ae>'`. You must name your waiver file
> matching the output the previous `git` command

2. Go to the `waivers/` folder and sign the new file with your GPG
key.

    ```sh
    gpg --no-version --armor --sign "John Smith <john@example.com>"
    ```

3. Add the new file and its signature to your next commit.

> [!CAUTION]
> Failure to provide your signed waiver will render any contribution
> attempt ineligible for merging.


Questions

Am I doing this correctly?
Is this enough to keep the project free of copyright claims forever?
Should I ask for the public key of the signing key to check that every waiver is properly signed by the correct private key too?


Note that in some jurisdictions, the only way to dedicate a work to the Public Domain is to commit suicide and wait 70 years. Are you sure that is a commitment you want to require from your contributors?

Please note that it's unclear what the "Unlicense" is – public domain dedication? License? PD dedication with a fallback license? Its terms are a bit contradictory. If you want a widely recognized PD dedication, consider using "CC 0".  It also clearly includes a fallback license for authors who are legally unable to dedicate creative works to the public domain (e.g. Germans like Jörg and me). However, CC 0 is not an Open Source license because it fails to ensure Software Freedom when considering issues around patents. Personally, I think PD-equivalent licenses like 0BSD are a neat solution.

maybe if I make a cult around the project that can be fixed for my German contributors lol

@amon I resolved to use the 0BSD


Am I doing this correctly?

Yes. Those steps are the same as what is needed for signing a Contributor License Agreement (CLA), which is a well known way to get an explicit statement from contributors that they agree to the license terms you expect for contributions.

Is this enough to keep the project free of copyright claims forever?

No. There is nothing that prevents me from taking your game engine, making a modification and redistributing that under a regular copyright license (not public domain).

Should I ask for the public key of the signing key to check that every waiver is properly signed by the correct private key too?

When a conflict arises that involves the question "Did John Doe really waive his copyright interests", you need to be able to verify the signature to prove that the waiver was really signed by John Doe and not by an imposter.
You can ask the committer to send you the public key, which can prove that the signature was made by this committer, but doesn't prove that the person is John Doe.
A better way is to obtain the public key from a key store where you can establish, through a web of trust, that the key actually belongs to John Doe.

As a side note, be aware that by choosing the UNLICENSE, you are excluding people from certain jurisdictions from contributing to your project.
For example, the copyright law in Germany doesn't allow an author to dedicate their work to the public domain. Even if they sign the waiver, that would not be accepted by German courts as a release of their copyright interests.

About the last part: For something copyleft-y that's valid in more if not all jurisdictions, consider EUPL. For something that releases to public domain or to the greatest extent possible by local law, consider CC0. Do keep in mind that Fedora refuses CC0 software due to "patent rights explicitly not being waived under the license".

@ave since my mother tongue is Spanish and Spain is a member of the EU, probably the EUPL may fit as an alternative to the UNLICENSE and to the CC0


No. There is nothing that prevents me from taking your game engine, making a modification and redistributing that under a regular copyright license (not public domain).

I'm okay with that as long as it does not sabotage the main project, I think

I had multiple long comments, so I think its best to just write them in an answer.
First off, in many major software jurisdictions (particularly the USA and perhaps Germany?) it may not in fact be possible to manually place new work in the Public Domain. The "Unlicensed" you point to has no provision for this whatsoever, so I wouldn't consider it adequate to the purpose at all. It could in fact put your users at legal jeapordy.
What I've used for this for the last 2 decades is CC0, which first tries to place the work in the Public Domain, but has "fall back" clauses to instead do the best its possible to do if Public Domain isn't an option.

Should any part of the Waiver for any reason be judged legally invalid
or ineffective under applicable law, then the Waiver shall be
preserved to the maximum extent permitted taking into account
Affirmer's express Statement of Purpose. In addition, to the extent
the Waiver is so judged Affirmer hereby grants to each affected person
a royalty-free, non transferable, non sublicensable, non exclusive,
irrevocable and unconditional license to exercise Affirmer's Copyright
...  ...for any purpose whatsoever

Many entities aside from myself, both large and small, have used this license in the last 2 decades, so it should be well understood when encountered.
Secondly, if the work really is put in the "public domain", and the contributions are as well (they are given to you with the same CC0 license?) then a second carefully worded waiver isn't really necessary. If its really in PD, then they don't have copyright anyway. If its not, then the CC0 license they gave it to you under has you and all your downstream users covered.
Thirdly, if you are concerned about some future contributor taking this "Public Domain" work and turning around to sell it themselves as a closed-source product, then you don't want Public Domain (or CC0). That's one of the things its meant to allow. Of course you and anyone else can still use the PD (CC0) version all they want too, so it may be dumb to pay someone for a closed version (unless it adds something nice worth paying for), but this should be one of the things you'd be happy to see with your CC0 project.

I hear that Fedora don't accept CC0 because of patents aren't waived. Do you have any of your software on Fedora, by chance?

@shackra the vast majority of licenses do not concern themselves with patents. Open source does not mean free-of-patents (which arguably is not nice). Apache has some provisions in that regard.

@shackra - My typical license is GPL with linking/inclusion exceptions. CC0 I usually will use only for libraries I either am hoping someone else will pick up and maintain, or I'm hoping to eventually put forward as part of a standard or larger library, and don't want licensing to be a barrier to use for anyone, either commercial or Free Software. The only thing I released I know of being in a Linux distribution had a GPL+linking license, and that was quite a while ago.

@shackra - Did a bit of confusing searching. According to your profile you are in Costa Rica. I did a quick check and it looks to me like your jurisdiction does not allow for manually putting things in Public Domain (but IANAL), so that's probably out. It does look like the 0BSD you mentioned in the question comments would work for them though. I'm not sure why that license is better for them wrt patents than CC0. Its like one sentence and a huge disclaimer of lability. There's like nothing in it. But that's Fedora's business I guess.

Perhaps they are more concerned about them getting sued over patents than they are about their users.
